# How to disable WiFi on Glass for testing?

Tags: google-glass, android-settings

I want to develop a receiver for Google Glass which will detect the WiFi state of Glass and depending on that state show some information to user.

The receiver will listen for `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` so that I can catch the event and after that check the status of the internet. It will not only detect the internet availability but will also show if Glass is timing out when pinging any specific IP address from any apps of glass.

I have tested the receiver on another Android device and it's working fine. But now I want to test the app on Glass. In order to test, I want to disable WiFi; however, Glass only shows options in settings for forgetting the current WiFi network and connecting to a nearby network.

How can I disable WiFi on Glass temporarily?

Comment: Zach Thank you very much for editing the question and make it more readable. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From default settings of glass its not possible to disable WiFi. To do the things you have to follow some instructions and install android default launcher and settings so that you can get the settings UI as your android device and do the rest of the desire works.

I am describing the whole process here :

1. At first you have to download these two apk.

   - Settings.apk - http://goo.gl/EqV8u
   - Launcher2.apk - http://goo.gl/ytfSn
2. After that you have to install these two apps into your glass by ADB :

   ```
   1. adb install Settings.apk          2. adb install Launcher2.apk
   ```

**Please be careful not to check the “Use as Default” box or you will not be able to access your Glass Settings until you uninstall Launcher2.apk.**

After complete installing go to your settings and select launcher. After selecting android default launcher you will get the setting UI as like as your android device. Now you can do whatever you want like WiFi enable/disable, Bluetooth enable/disable and etc. But there have some issues which not working like Bluetooth Tethering, Data Usage , Airplane Mode and some more features.

[Details process of using the settings and launcher and not working features.](http://www.glassxe.com/2013/05/23/settings-apk-and-launcher2-apk-from-the-hacking-glass-session-at-google-io/)

If you want to uninstall the installed app at first see your app packages name and delete the app from the devices using below script :

```
adb shell pm list packages [see all of your installed app list]

abd shell pm uninstall -k com.packagename [your app by specific package name]
```

After above script you will get your previous glass settings.

Here is the excellent video where all these process has been described in nice way.

[Voiding Your Warranty: Hacking Glass](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332704837)

Comment: Hi Abu Bakkar! Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I've encountered some problems. It did not work for me. I also followed the video. I installed both apk's but when I tap on "Launcher" it just doesn't do something. Do you have any ideas why it does so? Thanks again

Comment: It fails while trying to instantiate the Vibrator service: `java.lang.InstantiationError: android.os.Vibrator`.

Answer (score 2):

Well as you already know we cannot disable/enable wifi and bluetooth through the native settings application(and I really don't know why). But what we know is that Google Glasses is a bit special Android device on which we can do a lot of stuff that can be done on a regular android device(such as a phone). Among "the stuffs" that can be done is **enabling/disabling wifi and bluetooth programatically!** In order to do that you must create your own small project and include the following lines:

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

    boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();

    //Disable bluetooth
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
```

after running your small application that disables wifi and bluetooth you can navigate to your glass settings and **see that both wifi and bluetooth are OFF**. If you access one of them it asks you to turn them back on. **At least it works for Google Glass 19.1** (this is my current version).

Comment: Considerations: 1) you must import com.google.glass.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter instead of android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter; 2) You must add the following permissions for this snippet to work: `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`, `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`, `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`. Other than that, it's the simplest solution provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made an app that should let you toggle wifi on and off right from the menu.

Either say "okay glass, power options" or navigate to the card under the "okay glass" menu structure.

Working on bluetooth for later.  Based the app on the link below.

my app
https://github.com/afzaman/Power-Options-GoogleGlass

resources:
http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using-code

Comment: While your answer might be helpful, it currently contains no useful information directly in the post itself. An answer should be self-contained without relying on external resources. Please edit your post to include a code snippet or similar information to make it useful in itself.