# Disable WiFi in Google Glass

Tags: android-manifest, google-glass, google-gdk, wifimanager

I am desperately looking for an issue in order to be able to switch OFF/ON the WiFi in Google Glass using GDK.

I tried using the WifiManager but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
WifiManager  wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);   
wifi.isWifiEnabled();// return true, wifi is enabled
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
wifi.isWifiEnabled();// return true, wifi is enabled
```

I also added these permissions in my Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Glass version : XE18.11

Can anyone help me to disable WiFi on Google Glass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable WiFi on Glass for testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305083/how-to-disable-wifi-on-glass-for-testing)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know till now its not possible to access the WiFi from your code using GDK. I faced same problem and wrote a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305083/how-to-disable-wifi-on-glass-for-testing). We have to wait for official release version of Google Glass OS where they will provide the access of WiFi from Glass.